# Intercept Clipboard Paste Event in Console Application

Tags: c, windows, winapi, clipboard, line-endings

Using Visual Studio 2017 (current patchlevel, 15.8.7), any text copied from an LF-only file that gets pasted into a console loses the newline information.  So all the text appears to be on one line.

I'm free to change the console application being pasted into, which currently uses [ReadConsole()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole).  I'm wondering if there's anything that can be done to intercept the paste command and process it to honor the plain newlines.  There are some lower-level console APIs like [ReadConsoleInput()](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/console/readconsole) which seem to mean re-implementing all the cursor control and line editing logic.  I'm likely to want to do that anyway at some point...but if I did, would there be a way to hook the paste (not just Ctrl-V, but more abstractly, such as from menus?)

If it's not possible to work around, then there's no choice but to call it Visual Studio's fault.  It seems to be a popular kind of problem in programmer's editors on Windows--it's mentioned here [in a closed issue for VScode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22688), and in a [still open issue for Atom](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/8365)...which has a nice animation of the same old problem:

[image: demo of atom collapsing multiline LF-only input into single-line notepad data]

Like I say, in my case it's not Notepad I'm worried about...but a Windows Console application I can alter, and ideally make robust to this kind of paste.

But if there's no other option, I'd be interested in if anyone knows how to tell Visual Studio to paste content from a LF-only file into multiple lines in the console...by canonizing it to CR-LF on copy (but hopefully not corrupting all-LF files during editing because of this).  :-/